# How to know that an animation clip has finished?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

So there are **two ways** [*I got by search if there is any other way please share*] to do this.

- isPlaying Property (Example 1)
- Animation Time (Example 2)

Both I don't want to use as first way is using **Co-routine** which i don't want to use
and second is using **time** and if  increase the animation speed then time will not work correctly, thus affect codes.

**Example 1**

```
   public class AnimationSequancePlayer : MonoBehaviour {


    public Animation animation; // The animation we want to play the clips in.
    public AnimationClip[] animationClips; // The animation clips we want to play in order.

    int _currentClipOffset;

    void Start()
    {
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in animationClips)
        {
            animation.AddClip(clip, clip.name); // Make sure the animation player contains all of our clips.
        }
        PlaySequence();
    }

    public void PlaySequence()
    {
        _currentClipOffset = 0; // Reset the index to start at the beginning.
        PlayNextClip();
    }

    public void StopSequence()
    {
        animation.Stop();
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    void PlayNextClip()
    {
        animation.Play(animationClips[_currentClipOffset].name); // Play the wanted clip
        if (_currentClipOffset != animationClips.Length)
        { // Check if it's the last animation or not.
            StartCoroutine(WaitForAnimationEnd(() => PlayNextClip())); // Listen for end of the animation to call this function again.
            _currentClipOffset++; // Increase index for next time;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForAnimationEnd(Action onFinish)
    {
        while (animation.isPlaying)
        { // Check if the animation is playing or not
            yield return null;
        }
        if (onFinish != null) { onFinish(); } // Call the function give in parameter.
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
 if (GetComponent<Animation>()["Move Crane"].time >= 3f)
        {
         ///logic after animation reached at specified time specified time

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried _Animation Events_?

Comment: I am using max animation not unity3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short code snippet able me to do this.  Description of code given in the comments also. helpful for future users.

```
bool animationClipPlaying = false;
void Update()
{
     if (GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying(clipNameCompare))
     {
         //as animation start to play true the bool
         animationClipPlaying = true; //true this for comparsion
     }
     //if animation is not playing and the bool is true then, animation finished
     else if (!GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying(clipNameCompare) && animationClipPlaying)
     {
         Debug.Log(clipNameCompare : " has finished");
         //False so that this condition run only once
         aanimationClipPlaying = false; 
     }
}
```